# Creating an Exception Report in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have 2 tabs of data - one with actuals and one with goals.

**Sales Tab**

[image]

**Goal Tab**

[image]

I'm trying to create an exception report that only includes names of those that did not meet their goals. In this case, it should return Alex and Fred only.

I've tried the following code (below), but it is returning Alex and Katie, which is not correct. It also includes blank rows for everyone else, when ideally, I would like to skip those completely.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(Goal!A2:A6,Sales!A2:B6,2,FALSE)<VLOOKUP(Sales!A2:A6,Goal!A2:B6,2,FALSE),Goal!A2:A6,"")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6<VLOOKUP(A2:A6,D2:E6,2,0))
```

Or:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6<SUMIF(D2:D6,A2:A6,E2:E6))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The second formula works exactly as I need!

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(IFS(XLOOKUP(D2:D6,A2:A6,B2:B6)<E2:E6,D2:D6),3)
```

---

Or,

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,COUNTIFS(D2:D6,A2:A6,E2:E6,">"&B2:B6))
```

---